# What should this piece of .properties file look like in a .yml file?

Tags: file, properties, yaml

how to convert this .properties file to .yml file?

```
remote.security.oauth2.audiences=https://example.com
remote.security.oauth2.jwts[0].issuer-uri=https:https://example2.com
remote.security.oauth2.jwts[0].jwk-set-uri=https://example3.com
remote.security.oauth2.jwts[1].issuer-uri=https://example4.com
remote.security.oauth2.jwts[1].jwk-set-uri=https://example5.com
```

and yml example file

Comment: remote.security.authorizations[0].path=/api/users/{caid}/bankaccount
remote.security.authorizations[0].verbs=GET
remote.security.authorizations[0].authorities=BANK_ACCOUNT_VIEW

remote.security.authorizations[1].path=/api/users/{caid}/bankaccounts/{id}
remote.security.authorizations[1].verbs=GET
remote.security.authorizations[1].authorities=BANK_ACCOUNT_VIEW

remote.security.authorizations[2].path=/api/users/{caid}/banks
remote.security.authorizations[2].verbs=GET
remote.security.authorizations[2].authorities=BANK_ACCOUNT_EDIT

Comment: above there is another example of what I need to convert into a yaml format

Comment: there are some online editor like [mageddo](http://mageddo.com/tools/yaml-converter) which you can use to convert files to yaml files.